# Bezier Curve for some reason seriously messing up

Tags: bezier-curves

[image: The bezier curve has been rotated so that's the problem(most probably), how do I fix it?]

The bezier curve has been rotated so that's the problem(most probably), but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable viewing the curve's normals in edit mode using the overlay dropdown.

[image: overlays drop down]

[image: normals enabled.]

If your curve is twisted, this will show up clearly in the angle of the normals:

[image: twisted normals]

Unfortunately the only way I know to fix it is to select individual control points and either change their vector type to automatic (by typing VA) or by rotating the control point until the alignment looks good.